# Codeigniter CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array() error

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have the following model function

```
function list_get($id){
    $this->load->database();
    $query = $this->db-> select('*')
        ->from('lists')
        ->join('list_items', 'list_items.items_list_id = lists.list_id')
        ->where('items_list_id', $id);
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

And I get this error

> CI_DB_mysqli_driver::row_array()

when trying to display the cell value in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because I forgot to add `get()->`  the return should be `return $query->get()->row_array();`